# Writing high performance code and exception handling

Tags: c#

In a high performance C# program (where performance is the no1 concern), what sacrifices would be made to the code?

For example, how would exception handling change (less exceptions thrown/same no of exceptions caught?)?

I ask as I used to work in a monitoring company where a collector was written.

Thanks

Comment: "performance is the no1 concern" How can performance ever be the number one concern? Isn't it more important that your program actually does something useful and valuable? Otherwise, why not just write `while (true) {}` and call it a day?

Comment: I can see what you mean, but given the volume of data to collect etc, that was just the priority set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should `Throw` exceptions only when is strictly needed as it could leads the performance 
What’s the alternative to exception handling then?

You write code to check the input values and return values of each one of your methods and pass a return value back up to the caller.

http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2004/12/13/performance-issues-with-exception-handling/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11265/Performance-implications-of-Exceptions-in-NET

Answer (score 1):

You can measure performance by yourself and see how much exception handling slows the code down. Generally, if an exception is thrown, it is very wasteful, but if no exception is thrown, `try ... catch` slows the code only by a bit.

Another point: Linq is slower that simple iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should only be thrown in exceptional cases.  They should not be used for flow control.  A good goal is to be able to run your application under the debugger with normal use and exceptions should not be thrown.

If that's the case, in a high performance app, the cost of exceptions shouldn't be as much of a concern if they are truly exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is slow. By default, `Exception` instances are, what the name implies, an exception.
However if you expect them to occure a lot, you can decide to throw less `Exception` objects and handle the logical exceptions in another way. In other words, they became expected.

In the case they actually are unexpected, you can try to handle them earlier in the stack. A solution would be by using `bool` or `enum` retVals.   Rethrowing exceptions causes loss of performance.

Answer (score 0):

`Exception`s are the best way to handle exceptional circumstances. If some condition is expected then check for it with a conditional statement like `if`.

Apart from these generic rules, how much maintainability are you willing to sacrafice for performance? You could always write the code in assembler.